# Passing keywords recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I've got a function that looks like this:

```
def bootstrap(instrument, parallel_process=True, **kw):
    prices = instrument.prices(**kw)
```

I want to be able to pass through keyword arguments, so the inner bits know what to do.

I'm going to call it all with something like:

```
bootstrap(my_instrument, parallel_process=True, key1=True, key2=45)
```

I'd like the latter parts to go through to prices. It will pass through several layers in my code.

Am I doing this right? It seems then impossible to set default keyword args.

So this:

```
def prices(ccy_index=True, **kw):
  print(ccy_index)
```

Won't work when `ccy_index=False` is passed in `**kw`- it still thinks `ccy_index=True`

This strategy is a mess, and I'm concerned it's brittle. What I wanted was a set of global options that all the different bits of the code could lift their relevant bits out of, or otherwise default to something configured in the function. In other words, like keyword arguments, but defined recursively.

Comment: I don't think I'm following your "won't work" scenario - could you provide a proper SSCCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
def prices(**kw_in):
   kw = dict(ccy_index=True) # Defaults
   kw.update(kw_in)
   print(kw["ccy_index"])
```

In this way, you can pass arguments around recursively via `**kw` and also have assigned defaults at every stage.

Using the above code:

```
>>> prices()
True
>>> prices(ccy_index=True)
True
>>> prices(ccy_index=False)
False
```

Comment: That's really quite elegant, I love it! Thank you! :)